# Dualbooting 16.04 and win10 - win10 no longer booting after changing ubuntu partition

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Win10, dual booting via grub 2.02, on an old MSI GE-60 laptop.

Recently I've expanded my home partition on Ubuntu (by shrinking the swap partition, via gparted with a live ubuntu flashdrive). They are currently as follows:

- sda1 (winRE tools)
- sda2 (EFI System partition)
- sda3 (Microsoft reserved partition)
- sda4 windows partition
- sda5
- sda6 windows partition
- sda7 ubuntu partition
- sda8 ext4
- sda9 linux-swap
- sda10 ext4 linux home

I could not easily access the windows partitions in Ubuntu. I encountered the windows hibernation error many times and had to use the following command to be able to access the windows partitions in Ubuntu: sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda6.

Now I can no longer boot into win10. Whenever I select windows in the grub prompt, I encounter the following errors/messages:

```
preparing automatic repair
diagnosing your pc
Automatic Repair: your PC did not start correctly. Press restart to restart your PC, which can sometimes fix the problem. You can also press "Advanced options" to try other options to repair your PC.
```

Did I cause problems with the repartitioning? I've tried getting back in ubuntu and unmounting the windows drives (which are still accessible in ubuntu), but doing so and rebooting into windows still returns the errors above.

Any clues would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `Advanced options` ?

Comment: Yes: "startup repair" did not work. I don't have a system recovery image. "System restore" won't allow me to proceed - it says "you must enable system protection on this drive" and "next" button is greyed out.